# How to write the command statement to call customized function briefly?

Tags: functions, command

I have written the function im `.vimrc`:

```
function! Rep(raw,dest) range
python3 << EOF
#omit all the codes
EOF
endfunction
```

In `ex mode`, i can use it with `1,10call Rep("raw","dest")` or `3,15call Rep("raw","dest")`,add command statement to make the call more shorter.

```
command! Rep -nargs=* -range=N   <line1>,<line2>call Rep(raw,dest)
```

It encounter an error when to type `1,10Rep("raw","dest")` in editing a file.

```
No range allowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be reading the documentation one paragraph at a time, without the required foundational knowledge.

"Defining command-line commands" is introduced in chapter 40 of the user manual: `:help 40.2` and further documented under `:help user-commands`.

**First issue**: you don't call functions and execute commands the same way:

```
:1,10call FunctionName("argument")
:1,10CommandName argument
```

In the first case, a function call, the function is called with argument `"argument" one time for each line in range 1-10, unless you added the modifier` range` to the function definition, in which case the function is called once and assumed to handle lines by itself.

In the second case, a command execution, the command is called once with argument `argument`, and assumed to handle the range somehow. You don't use parentheses, here.

Instead of the pointless:

```
:1,10Rep("raw","dest")
```

you are supposed to do:

```
:1,10Rep raw dest
```

**Second issue**: the `N` in `-range=N` is a placeholder that you are supposed to replace with an actual number.

This is *invalid*:

```
-range=N
```

This is *valid*:

```
-range=4
```

IMO, it seems unlikely that you actually want `-range=4` anyway, so I would suggest (re-)reading `:help :command-range` carefully.

**Third issue**: your command definition doesn't pass the arguments to the function so the arguments are useless, both at the command level and at the function level. If you always pass the same arguments to your function, then turn them into variables.

Let's review a bunch of scenarios…

**Scenario #0**: you need to handle the range within the function.

1. Rewrite your function definition:

   ```
   function! Rep() range
       echo a:firstline
       echo a:lastline
       [...]
   endfunction
   ```
2. Rewrite your command definition:

   ```
   command! -range Rep <line1>,<line2>call Rep()
   ```
3. Use it like so:

   ```
   :1,10Rep
   1
   10
   ```

**Scenario #1**: you don't need the command to pass any argument to the function.

1. Rewrite your function definition:

   ```
   function! Rep() range
       let l:raw = "raw"
       let l:dest = "dest"
       echo a:firstline
       echo a:lastline
       echo l:raw
       echo l:dest
       [...]
   endfunction
   ```
2. Rewrite your command definition:

   ```
   command! -range Rep <line1>,<line2>call Rep()
   ```
3. Use it like so:

   ```
   :1,10Rep
   1
   10
   raw
   dest
   ```

**Scenario #2**: you need to pass a set number of arguments to the function.

1. Rewrite your function definition:

   ```
   function! Rep(raw, dest, ...) range
       echo a:firstline
       echo a:lastline
       echo a:raw
       echo a:dest
       [...]
   endfunction
   ```

   The `...` means that function will accept more arguments, accessible via `a:1`, `a:2`, etc.
2. Rewrite your command definition:

   ```
   command! -range -nargs=+ Rep <line1>,<line2>call Rep(<f-args>)
   ```
3. Use it like so:

   ```
   :1,10Rep foo bar
   1
   10
   foo
   bar
   ```

**Scenario #3**: you don't particularly care about the number of arguments and you are fine with positional arguments.

1. Rewrite your function definition:

   ```
   function! Rep(...) range
       echo a:firstline
       echo a:lastline
       if a:0 >= 1
           echo a:1
       endif
       if a:0 >= 2
           echo a:2
       endif
       [...]
   endfunction
   ```
2. Rewrite your command definition:

   ```
   command! -range -nargs=* Rep <line1>,<line2>call Rep(<f-args>)
   ```
3. Use it like so:

   ```
   :1,10Rep
   1
   10
   :1,10Rep foo bar baz
   1
   10
   foo
   bar
   baz
   ```

And so on… see `:help user-functions` and `:help user-commands`.

Comment: Syntax is `:command [{attr}...] {cmd} {repl}`, so `-range` and `-nargs` come before `Rep`. You knew that, and probably unintentionally repeated OP's mistake (which explains the "No range allowed" error).

Comment: Hmm… my trust issues are not so deep after all.